# How to eliminate error warnings about ini_set?

Tags: wordpress, warnings, ini-set

my wordpress error log is filling up with this message:

```
PHP Warning:  ini_set() has been disabled for security reasons in  
             /home/mywebsite/public_html/wp-includes/load.php on line 271
```

that line reads: `ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );`

any suggestions on *how to eliminate error warnings?*

Comment: Comment that line out of the file - add a `//` at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing that error because the `XMLRPC_REQUEST` constant is set to true, which causes WordPress to try and disable error reporting with the following:

```
if ( defined( 'XMLRPC_REQUEST' ) )
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
```

Editing core Wordpress files is **not recommended**. They will be overwritten when you update or autoupdate. The correct way to correct for this is to edit the `php.ini` file on the server and remove `ini_set` from the [`disable_functions`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) directive.

You could also set `display_errors` to `Off`, or alternatively change the [`error_reporting`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) directive as well to prevent warnings from being shown.

```
error_reporting = E_ERROR
```

You could also try using the [`error_reporting()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) PHP function in `wp-config.php` to try and disable warnings as well.

```
// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);

// Only show errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

One other suggestion I have never tried to is to override the `php.ini` values via `.htaccess` which may or may not work on your host - [see this guide](http://forums.glowhost.com/knowledge-base/how-fix-ini_set-has-been-disabled-security-reasons-2503.html).

Comment: thanks I put this in my wp-config.php  error_reporting(NULL);
@ini_set('display_errors', 0);
@ini_set('log_errors','On');
@ini_set('display_errors','Off');